# Correctly referencing nested dictionaries and lists | Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

By doing

```
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    h2h=json.loads(response.text)
```

I receive the dictionary h2h which looks like this:

```
{'api': {'fixtures': [{'awayTeam': {'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/157.png',
                                    'team_id': 157,
                                    'team_name': 'Bayern Munich'},
                       'elapsed': 90,
```

I am now trying to do something with all fixtures of a certain team like this:

```
for i in h2h['api']['fixtures']: #for each fixture
        if ['awayTeam']['team_id']==team_id1:
           #do something...
```

Then I receive an error:

```
if ['awayTeam']['team_id']==(team_id1):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

For ['awayTeam'][0] I receive no error, which would mean that 'awayTeam' is a list.

Why is 'awayTeam' a list and not a dictionary? Isn't 'awayTeam' the first item in the 'fixtures' list?

How do I correctly reference 'team_id'?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi! Sometimes when there is only one item, the result is not a list but another dictionary containing the data that you want, I suggest to check the data type before and add logic for both cases accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going about referencing your dictionary and lists incorrectly. To get team ID, reference the dictionary as I have done below:

```
h2 = {'api': {'fixtures': [{'awayTeam': {'logo': 'https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/157.png','team_id': 157,'team_name': 'Bayern Munich'},'elapsed': 90}]}}

team_id1 = 157 # just to test if condition
for fixture in h2['api']['fixtures']:
    if fixture['awayTeam']['team_id'] == team_id1:
        print (fixture['awayTeam']['team_id'])
        # (do something with fixture['awayTeam']['team_id'])
```